# How to authenticate users when printing from iOS to a Windows IPP server

Tags: ios, authentication, printing, cups, airprint

I’ve built the ipp sample at https://github.com/istopwg/ippsample on my windows 10 laptop (Home edition) with Visual Studio 2017. I’m not using SSL. I want to produce PDF documents by printing to this from iOS devices and I want to be able, within ippserver, to identify the user who is printing.

This isn’t my area. I’ve little knowledge of ipp, http and c programming so am floundering a bit. I’m just aiming for a proof of concept to convince my employer this an area we should invest time in.

After much trawling of the web I came across guidance that led me to enable an iPAD to find ippserver and treat it as an AirPrint printer. I’ve included air=username,password in the TXT record because I thought this would result in the iPad user being prompted for these credentials when printing. This does have some effect. The iPad displays “Forget username and password” but it does not display a dialog to enter these. It still prints without authentication. I hope someone here can help me with this.

As an aside, the PDFs produced are corrupt. I haven’t spent any time yet trying to solve this but any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The corruption was solved by creating the file as binary. It turned out the corruption was just extra line feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me that ippserver in the sample code did not implement authentication so I added Basic authentication in the conventional way with little success until I also managed to get https working, which was difficult only because of my lack of knowledge of certificates and where to put them. Now my iOS device is sending username and password with each request in the standard basic authentication way.